# Referencing a C code-defined macro within its makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm writing some embedded firmware using C with arm-gcc and Eclipse.
Within my code is a FW version number defined as a macro.
I want to have that version appended to the build target file automatically.

For the sake of the example, let's say this is my main.h file:

```c
#ifndef MAIN_H__
#define MAIN_H__

#define FW_MAJOR_VERSION   1
#define FW_MINOR_VERSION   0
```

and the makefile:

```
TARGET     := fw_release
OUTPUT_DIR := out
...
generate_pkg:
   @gen_pkg $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET)_pkg.zip
```

where `gen_pkg` is some script to generate a firmware update package.

This would generate a file path like this: `out/fw_release_pkg.zip`

Ideally, I would like something like this:

```
generate_pkg:
   @gen_pkg $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET)_pkg_v$(FW_MAJOR_VERSION).$(FW_MINOR_VERSION).zip
```

which would generate a file path like this: `out/fw_release_pkg_v1.0.zip`

Now I know I can define the version within the makefile and reference that within the code (basically the other way around), but that has 2 problems:

1. Every time I change the makefile it triggers a compilation of the entire code which takes a few minutes.
2. I have two separate build configurations (release and debug), each using its own makefile, and that would require me to update the two separately.

Comment: Maybe you can include `include version.make` in both `Makefile`s...

Comment: If you are using `GNUmake` then your two problems are non-existent as you can easily include a true version file with proper dependencies. Doing it your way (retrieving from source code) should only be done in ... well I can't even think of a case where it should be done. Version numbering is a central issue which is one level higher on the abstraction ladder than some constants.

Answer (score 3):

The approach I'd take would be to define the version number elements in the Makefile, and burn those in to your code using cflags.

In the Makefile:

```
FW_VERSION_MAJOR=1
FW_VERSION_MINOR=1
FW_VERSION_MICRO=0a

FW_VERSION = $(FW_VERSION_MAJOR).$(FW_VERSION_MINOR).$(FW_VERSION_MICRO)

CFLAGS += -DFW_VERSION_MAJOR=$(FW_VERSION_MAJOR)
CFLAGS += -DFW_VERSION_MINOR=$(FW_VERSION_MINOR)
CFLAGS += -DFW_VERSION_MICRO=$(FW_VERSION_MICRO)

debug_build:
    $(CC) -DDEBUG=1 $(OBJECTS) -o $(OUTPUT)

release_build:
    $(CC) -DDEBUG=0 $(OBJECTS) -o $(OUTPUT)
```

Then it's a fairly easy matter to burn the correct version into your debug and
non-debug pkg generation - and you only have to change the firmware version info
in one place.

Comment: You can also add a "version.h" file, in which you can check if these are defined or not - helps with the IDEs...
Also, the version can be include-d from separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll have to parse `main.h` one way or another.

Assuming that you're using `gcc` or `clang`:

```
generate_pkg:   main.h
        @gen_pkg "$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$$(echo FW_MAJOR_VERSION/FW_MINOR_VERSION | $(CC) -P -E -include main.h -x c -)_pkg.zip"
```

If your `main.h` is more complicated than that, you'll have to add all your `$(CFLAGS)` and other default options to the `$(CC)` command.